# Jquery not loaded by default in wordpress 5.6

Tags: jquery

I just installed a fresh WP 5.6 and I realized that there is no JQuery at all inside the blog (it is still inside wp-includes/jq/jquery, but it is not loaded by default: jQuery or $ return undefined function.

Has JQuery been removed by default from WP ?

I am trying to develop a WP plugin that uses Jquery (ajax calls): Should I manually load JQuery with wp_enqueue_scripts ?

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
   function my_jquery_enqueue() {
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
```

Comment: jQuery was never loaded by default. It was only loaded if it was needed by a theme or plugin. If you are not using one that does, which is increasingly likely these days, then it won’t be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that jQuery is loaded by adding it to the `$dependencies` array when you enqueue your script.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse384152_enqueue_my_scripts' );
function wpse384152_enqueue_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', '/path/to/my/script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

That will ensure that a) jQuery gets loaded and b) it gets loaded *before* your script.

### References

- [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)
- [Default scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-and-js-libraries-included-and-registered-by-wordpress)